# How do virtual-photons curve in a magetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, magnetic-fields, virtual-particles

From what I understand photons only move in straight lines unless reflected or refracted (other than influences from gravitational fields and their usual wavelike movement). And since they are a fundamental force carrier I am having difficulty understanding how they are "pulled" into a pole of a magnet after leaving the opposite end. How does this occur?

[image: Curves in magnetic field:]

Comment: Which photons? Probably there is a mismatch between your question, referring to fundamental interactions, and the picture of a "macroscopic" magnet. Microscopically, if you talk about virtual photon (there are an infinity of them)  you have objects with well definite energies/frequencies/wavelengths and hence, for the **uncertainty principle**, no sense of a straight trajectory. For example, Feynman diagrams doesn't represent trajectories but momenta! Real photons are non-interacting objects moving in free space on straight lines; you can approximate their behaviour as that of waves..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field lines in your drawing are not the trajectories of photons. The field lines show the direction of the force on a test magnetic dipole. The force, and therefore its direction, is mediated by virtual photons (or can be described that way) but those photons will travel in straight lines just like ordinary photons.